# Running into a snag with C socket program

Tags: c, sockets

I am currently working on a server-client pair that will spell check a txt file when sent to the server, but my code just hangs midway through. Hoping someone with a different perspective could show me what I'm not seeing. Here is the server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int welcomeSocket, newSocket;
  char *dictionary[100000];
  char buffer[1024];
  struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
  struct sockaddr_storage serverStorage;
  socklen_t addr_size;

//create socket. 0 means TCP
welcomeSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
//address family -> internet
serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
//set port number using htons for byte ordering
serverAddr.sin_port = htons(19703);
//set IP to localhost
serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY); //any IP
//set bits of the padding field to 0
memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);
//bind address to the socket
bind(welcomeSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
//listen on socket 19703, max 5 connections queued
if(listen(welcomeSocket,5) == 0)
  printf("Listening...\n");
else
  printf("Error\n");

//copy dictionary to array
  FILE *fp;
  char temp[100];
  fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  int pos = 0;
  while(fgets(temp, 1024, fp) != NULL){
      strtok(temp, "\n");     //remove trailing newline
      dictionary[pos] = temp;
      pos++;
  }

//accept creates a new socket for the incoming connection
addr_size = sizeof serverStorage;
newSocket = accept(welcomeSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverStorage, &addr_size);
printf("accepted...\n");

//receive word from client
  read(newSocket, buffer, 1024);
printf("read...\n");
//spit it back out (used in testing and debugging
  printf("The word is: %s", buffer);

//search dictionary array
  int i=0;
  int good=0;
  while(dictionary[i] != NULL){
    if(strcmp(buffer, dictionary[i])==0){
      printf("%s - OK\n", buffer);
      good++;
      i++;
    }
  }
if(good == 0){
  printf("%s - MISSPELLED\n", buffer);
}
  return 0;
}//end main
```

As you can see I have some printf statements for debugging. To show you where it hangs (strange spot) the output I get when my client sends is:

```
Listening...
accepted...
read...
```

I can't tell why this is happening. Thank you to anyone who can shed some light. I'm in for a lot more work on this one, as I've still got to implement multithreading and semaphores and stuff.

Comment: This is what a debugger is for: to execute your program, one line at a time, and give you the ability to examine the values of all variables on each step. Had you known how to use your debugger, and use it to run your program, you would've figured out this obvious bug much faster than preparing a post on stackoverflow.com, and wait for someone to, perhaps, give you an answer. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every developer. A likely second bug, in addition to this one, is that the string being sent over socket better be `\0` terminated, else this will randomly crash.

Comment: when calling system functions: (socket(), bind(), listen(), accept(), fopen(), read(), always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, 1)  consistently indent the code.  Increase the indent level after every opening brace '{'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces. 2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. I.E. 1024, 100000.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc. Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then using those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the desired command line parameters were actually entered.

Comment: regarding: `if(listen(welcomeSocket,5) == 0)
        printf("Listening...\n");
    else
        printf("Error\n");` when the call to `listen()` fails, output any error message to `stderr`, not `stdout` and include the OS text as to why it failed. Suggest using: `perror( "listen failed" );` as that will do the job.  Then since the program has now failed, call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );` as the next instruction as continuing to execute the program would be an error

Comment: for ease of readability, by us humans, insert appropriate horizontal spacing: inside parens, after semicolons, after commas, around C operators

Comment: this line: `dictionary[pos] = temp;` only copies a pointer however, the code actually wants to point to a 'stable' copy of the text.   Suggest using `strdup()`.   Note: remember that each such generated string will need to be (eventually) passed to `free()`

Comment: regarding: `while(fgets(temp, 1024, fp) != NULL){` 1) do not have to explicitly check for NULL  2) need to check `size_t pos;` to avoid overflowing the dictionary[] array.  Suggest: `while( pos < (sizeof dictionary / sizeof dictionary[0]) && fgets( temp, sizeof temp, fp ) )`

Comment: regarding: `while(dictionary[i] != NULL)`  this is undefined behavior because the array `dictionary[]` has not been initialized to all NULL.  suggest replacing: `char *dictionary[ 100000 ];` with: `char *dictionary[ 100000 ] = { NULL };`

Comment: Add \n to this line to make it flush: printf("The word is: %s", buffer);

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. corrects the problems listed in the comments
2. performs the desired functionality
3. cleanly compiles
4. has NOT been tested
5. properly checks for errors
6. leaves it to the OP to insert the code to cleanup before each call to `exit()`

And now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>   // socket()
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_DICTIONARY_ENTRIES 100000
#define MAX_BUFFER_LEN         1024
#define MAX_TEMP_BUF           100


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int welcomeSocket;
    int newSocket;

    char *dictionary[ MAX_DICTIONARY_ENTRIES ] = {NULL};
    char buffer[ MAX_BUFFER_LEN +1]; // plus 1 to allow for NUL terminator byte

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    struct sockaddr_storage serverStorage;
    socklen_t addr_size;

    if( 2 != argc )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <dictionaryFileName>\n", argv[0] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, correct number of arguments

    //create socket. 0 means TCP
    welcomeSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if( 0 > welcomeSocket )
    {
        perror( "socket failed" );
        // TODO: cleanup
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, socket successful

    //address family -> internet
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    //set port number using htons for byte ordering
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(19703);

    //set IP to localhost
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY); //any IP

    //set bits of the padding field to 0
    memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);

    //bind address to the socket
    if( 0 != bind( welcomeSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr) ) )
    {
        perror( "bind failed" );
        // TODO: cleanup
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, bind successful

    //listen on socket 19703, max 5 connections queued
    if( listen( welcomeSocket, 5 ) != 0 )
    {
        perror( "listen failed" );
        printf("Error\n");
        // TODO: cleanup
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, listen successful

    printf( "listening...\n" );

    //copy dictionary to array
    FILE *fp;
    char temp[ MAX_TEMP_BUF ];
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if( !fp )
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        // TODO: cleanup
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    size_t pos = 0;
    while( pos < (sizeof dictionary / sizeof dictionary[0])
        && fgets( temp, sizeof temp, fp ) )
    {
        strtok(temp, "\n");     //remove trailing newline
        dictionary[pos] = strdup(temp);
        if( !dictionary[pos] )
        {
            perror( "strdup failed" );
            // TODO: cleanup
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, strdup successful

        pos++;
    }

    fclose( fp );

    //accept creates a new socket for the incoming connection
    addr_size = sizeof serverStorage;
    newSocket = accept(welcomeSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverStorage, &addr_size);
    if( 0<= newSocket )
    {
        perror( "accept failed" );
        // TODO: cleanup
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, accept successful

    printf("accepted...\n");

    //receive word from client
    ssize_t bytesread = read(newSocket, buffer, sizeof buffer);
    if( 0 >= bytesread )
    {
        perror( "read failed" );
        // TODO: cleanup
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, read successful

    buffer[bytesread] = '\0';  // terminate the string
    printf("read...\n");

    //spit it back out (used in testing and debugging
    printf("The word is: %s\n", buffer);

    //search dictionary array
    int good=0;
    for( size_t i=0; dictionary[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(buffer, dictionary[i])==0)
        {
            printf("%s - OK\n", buffer);
            good++;
            break; // exit 'for()' loop
        }
    }

    if( !good )
    {
        printf("%s - not found in dictionary\n", buffer);
    }

    close( welcomeSocket );
    close( newSocket );

    // TODO: other cleanup


    return 0;
}//end main
```